# Recreate SecurityGroup if cloudformation stack is deleted and the same security group already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I deleted a cloudformation stack but retained a few of the resources like the security groups. Now when I try to deploy the stack again it isn't able to create the security groups again since they already exist and the deployment fails. Is there any way I can replace these security groups that already exist with the ones from my cloudformation template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the existing resources via a different Cloud Formation Template. 
If you have captured the existing security groups information in the new CFN Template then, you can take either of two approaches, depending on your requirements:

1. **Approach:** Create same security groups with different name i.e. with a suffix "-cfn"(along with its association to the required resources) by the cloud formation template. Then, Delete the old security groups.

   - If old security group names were being referred in other CFN Template, then run an update on your CFN Template with old names for these security groups and they will be replaced with identical security group of old name.
   - If old security group ids are being referenced in other security groups which are not being referenced by this CFN template then, update those security groups with new security group ids before deleting the old security groups
   - *Advantage:* A running network flow per the security group rules won't be impacted by this change.
2. **Approach 2:** Delete the security groups rules first. Then, create them per the new CFN template.

   - *Advantage:* The names of security groups remain same.